# Set up server for simple iPhone game

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am looking for information on how to create and run a simple server game that will take turn information from one user, do some number crunching and pass the resultant information on to the other players in the game.

What I am looking for is a push in the right direction. While I have been coding for the iPhone for almost two years now, my server experience is limited to making a URL request to a PHP script that pulls information from a database and return it to the iPhone requesting the information. I have no idea how to take information from an iPhone and send it to other specific iPhone or players.

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated. Tutorials would be nice but even just a hint of how to go about doing this would be fantastic.

Thanks.

Comment: Lots of people use PHP and Rails for this. Sinatra might be just what you need. Might be worth asking the guys at http://urbanairship.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more experience on the Objective-C side, I recommend you use iOS 4.1's Game Center connectivity to connect your users. Once you've established a `GKSession` between your users, sending data to all the connected peers is a snap. You could do your number crunching on one device that acts as a server and send the result to the clients for processing. This is how I do the peer-to-peer gaming in my iOS game, [Cee-lo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cee-lo/id390557478?mt=8). Check out the [Game Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at creating a RESTful web service on PHP that accepts your players data.  This service can post the data to your database.  When other players request the data from your PHP page, it can just request the latest from the database, which should have the latest friends information.

This a fairly common pattern, you can lookup using JSON to send and receive between the iPhone and a PHP site.

[Creating a rest api with PHP](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/)

Comment: Just make sure to run it over HTTPS :)